# Airflow local install in Mac pointing Dag folder to Conda site packages instead of /Users/myuser/airflow/dags

Tags: macos, airflow

So I installed Airflow locally on my Mac (Big Sur 11.5) per install script below:

`https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html`

And I have my dag folder in:
`/Users/myuser/airflow/dags`

Config Changes made to airflow.cfg:

```
load_examples = False
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:password@localhost/airflow_db
executor = LocalExecutor
```

I then initialized db, started webserver and scheduler.

However, I am not able to see dags I load in my specified dagfolder. Instead I see a list of example dags that Airflow seems to be sourcing from `/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/`

I looked for other folks that may have run into same issue and that's how I turned the `load_examples = False`. Reran everything and still no luck.

Help overcome this last hurdle would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the same problem, did you find a solution in the meantime?